# I have ceased contact with a boy I sinned with, but described this sin to my friends. How do I repent this, and repent backbiting?

Tags: tawba, backbiting

I do my religious duties but have sinned recently.

Recently I was in a relationship (for 6 months) and we have crossed the line a few times (in the first 3 months) were we kissed and touched like married couples. We both felt very guilty and put rules so this does not happen again and reach something we will both really regret. After this he asked me not to mention this to anyone but I did mention this to 3 of my close friends and asked them to keep it a secret. (They have either forgotten; one of them I will not see within 2-3 years.)

Today we have broken up and not on speaking terms and my questions are the following:

1. I have read a hadith somewhere that anyone who has boasted a sin might not be forgiven by Allah. (Which scares me very much. I didn't know that at the time and I regret this very much.) Is this true?
2. I have also read that I must ask the forgiveness of the person I have backbitten. I, however, am not on speaking terms with the boy at the moment and feel if I tell him it will do more damage then good. He will only get upset and I will feel very bad. Am I required to ask for his forgiveness in this or do I just ask for Allah to forgive me?

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah
Your first answer -
Actually you know Allah  says that the person who commits shirk is not forgiven by Allah.But it doesn't mean that someone committed major shirk and repent and become Muslim but still he is not forgiven.Yes he may be forgiven but if he dies with shirk then on the day of Qiyamat he will not be forgiven.So as you have boasted upon committing sin.But now if you are repented Insha'Allah you will be forgiven.You should know that mercy of Allah is boundless.Islam tells us that if you ask for forgiveness to Allah then be sure about a response.

But I am sorry to give answer of your second question as I don't have sufficient knowledge regarding this.